# Why is the browser trying to load a /none page (with Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, performance, load, performance-testing

I'm building a Wordpress theme and one of the things I noticed is that the browser requests a page `/none` (example.com/none). I see this in the Network part of the inspector:

[image: Browser loading page /none]

(This is Chrome). As you can see, the browser spends 676 ms loading it and during that time it almost doesn't do/load anything else.

In a theme check (with a WP plugin) I also encountered the absence of `/none` as an error.

Is this usual browser behaviour for every website or is this pure Wordpress?
And what should I do to fix it (be it WP or browser behaviour)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is not a normal behaviour on wordpress sites. Have you checked changing the theme if it still occurs? If not, maybe there is some call for the file in your theme. Does it appear on every wordpress page? Normally, the archive pages include the "none" template file (template part) if there are no entries to be listed. Also try to disable your plugins to see if one of it causes the issue.

Comment: Hi @rank thanks for your help! I’ll check this afternoon if it appears on every page and if switching the theme helps. Can you point me to some documentation or sth about the none template, so that I can learn somewhat more about it? Has the template the name none.php? I’ll let you know this afternoon and many thanks. Ralph

Comment: The "none" can be a part of your template. Normally it can be found in "template-parts". This does not have anything special about it. It is just the template part that is called, when no entries are found. So it might be, that there is an if clause returning false and therefore loading the none-template. I would need some information about your template hierarchy of the theme you are using to tell you more.

Comment: Hello @rank thanks for pointing out that it is a theme issue and not a Wordpress one. When I was checking the inspector today in Firefox, my eye fell on the kind of file: an image. After a bit of digging, I found the problem: in some cases I would apply some CSS: `background-image: none`. That made the browser think I wanted an image with the url `/none`. I changed this to `background: none` and that fixed the whole problem. If you can add an answer that it is a theme-specific problem, I'll accept it. So after all it wasn't a the template file, but wrong CSS ;-). Cheers, Ralph

Comment: Happy to hear you found the reason :) . I added an answer for others maybe experiencing similar problems. Thank you very much! And have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be related to your theme files. You can have a look at the wordpress template hierarchy to find out all parts of your theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Deactivate your theme and use a standard theme. Deactivate all plugins. This way you can make sure that it has nothing to do with your wordpress installation or plugins, but is an issue caused by your theme.

The inspector of your browser might give you the right hints where you can start your search.